# Primefaces table with editable rows generateds duplicate gridcells

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Using PF 6.1, I have a Primefaces data table where I need to make certain cells editable. Most things are working fine, but when the page is refreshed, a duplicate empty  element is inserted for each cell, and those elements disappear if I edit a row (even if I cancel editing). If I have normally 5 columns, I see 5  with class ui-editable-column and correct content, but when I refresh the page, I see additional 5  with class ui-panelgrid-cell that contain the data, and the original 5  with class ui-editable-column which are empty and make the table misaligned. [image]

```
  <p:panel>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="myTable" editable="true"
                         var="var"
                         value="#{ManagementBean.values}"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorPosition="top" rows="25"
                         paginatorTemplate="..."
                         tableStyle="table-layout: auto">

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{ManagementBean.onRowEdit}" update="myTable"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{ManagementBean.onRowCancel}" update="myTable"/>

                <!-- cells that dont need to be edited, have duplicate input and output fields-->
                <p:column headerText="..." sortBy="...">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{var.name}"/></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><h:outputText value="#{var.name}"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <!-- Example of cell that gets edited -->
                <p:column headerText="...">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                       <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="..."/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="..." value="...">
                                <f:selectItems value="..." var="..."
                                               itemLabel="..." itemValue="..."/>
                            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Sure you don't have nested forms?

Comment: And tried PF 6.1

Comment: Using pf 6.1. I made sure there are not nested forms.

Comment: Switching back to primefaces v 5.3.11 seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Switching forward to 6.2 snapshot or a 6.1 elite version?

Comment: sticking to 5.3.11 for now.

Comment: Good luck, thanks for trying... cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant to the issue OP is facing, but I also encountered duplicated cells and I fixed it by changing:

```
<p:panelGrid></p:panelGrid>
```

to

```
<h:panelGrid></h:panelGrid>
```

this solves the duplication issue on my end.

Sample of my view page looks like the following:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <p:column>
        <p:row>
            <!-- contents... -->
        </p:row>
    </p:column>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Might be helpful to future readers.